# VBA - Error 1004

Tags: vba, function, match

This line shows a runtime error 1004, but I don't understand why:

> ```
> ActiveCell.Formula = "=MATCH(R" & i & "C16;R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15;0)"
> ```

```
Sub Call_Min()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim limit As Integer
    Sheets("AUX").Activate
    limit = ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value

    Sheets("DATA").Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 16).Select
    'ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(Range("F6:I6"))"
    For i = 6 To limit

      'MATCH(P6;F6:O6;0)
      ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i).Select
      ActiveCell.Formula = "=MIN(R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15)"

      ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Select
      ActiveCell.Formula = "=MATCH(R" & i & "C16;R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15;0)"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It should be `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` and not `ActiveCell.Formula`.

Comment: Change `ActiveCell.Formula` to  `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1Local `

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that vba is very US-English centric.  So either use `,` in place of `;` or use `.FormulaR1C1Local`:

```
Sub Call_Min()
Dim i As Integer
Dim limit As Integer

limit = Sheets("AUX").Range("B6").Value

Sheets("Sheet11").Activate
'ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 16).Select
'ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(Range("F6:I6"))"
For i = 6 To limit

      'MATCH(P6;F6:O6;0)
      Sheets("DATA").Range("P" & i).FormulaR1C1Local = "=MIN(R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15)"

      Sheets("DATA").Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1Local = "=MATCH(R" & i & "C16;R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15;0)"
Next i
End Sub
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) on how to avoid using `.Select` and why.

Comment: ++ for avoiding `Select` and `ActiveCell`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Call_Min()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim limit As Integer
    Sheets("AUX").Activate
    limit = ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value

    Sheets("DATA").Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 16).Select
    'ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(Range("F6:I6"))"
    For i = 6 To limit

      'MATCH(P6;F6:O6;0)
      ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i).Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15)"

      ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(R" & i & "C16,R" & i & "C6:R" & i & "C15,0)"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Two changes were made:

1. Usage of `FormulaR1C1` instead of `Formula`.
2. Replacing the `;` in the formulas for `,`.